# Sonar Web Page is not displayed

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube5.6

I'm unable to get the issue with my Sonar Configuration, in log I did't find any ERROR all tables are also created in database but my sonar home page is not loaded.

Here is log:

> --> Wrapper Started as Daemon Launching a JVM... Wrapper (Version
>   3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
>
> 2016.12.30 17:10:32 INFO  app[o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonarqube-5.6.4/temp
>   2016.12.30 17:10:33 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[es]: /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_102/jre/bin/java
>   -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonarqube-5.6.4/temp -javaagent:/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_102/jre/lib/management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer /opt/sonarqube-5.6.4/temp/sq-process2942922181507412713properties
>   2016.12.30 17:10:33 INFO   es[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Starting es
>   2016.12.30 17:10:33 INFO   es[o.s.s.EsSettings]  Elasticsearch listening on 127.0.0.1:9001
>   2016.12.30 17:10:33 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1483098032772] version[1.7.5], pid[4647],
>   build[00f95f4/2016-02-02T09:55:30Z]
>   2016.12.30 17:10:33 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1483098032772] initializing ...
>   2016.12.30 17:10:33 INFO   es[o.e.plugins]  [sonar-1483098032772] loaded [], sites []
>   2016.12.30 17:10:33 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.env]  [sonar-1483098032772] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/sda1)]],
>   net usable_space [167.1gb], net total_space [187.6gb], types [ext4]
>   2016.12.30 17:10:34 WARN   es[o.e.bootstrap]  JNA not found. native methods will be disabled.
>   2016.12.30 17:10:35 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1483098032772] initialized
>   2016.12.30 17:10:35 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1483098032772] starting ...
>   2016.12.30 17:10:35 INFO   es[o.e.transport]  [sonar-1483098032772] bound_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]}, publish_address
>   {inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]}
>   2016.12.30 17:10:35 INFO   es[o.e.discovery]  [sonar-1483098032772] sonarqube/LeFjRSLmQCm1hf-L51yDmg
>   2016.12.30 17:10:39 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.service]  [sonar-1483098032772] new_master
>   [sonar-1483098032772][LeFjRSLmQCm1hf-L51yDmg][NDL][inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]]{rack_id=sonar-1483098032772},
>   reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
>   2016.12.30 17:10:39 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1483098032772] started
>   2016.12.30 17:10:39 INFO   es[o.e.gateway]  [sonar-1483098032772] recovered [6] indices into cluster_state
>   2016.12.30 17:10:42 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is up
>   2016.12.30 17:10:42 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_102/jre/bin/java
>   -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonarqube-5.6.4/temp -javaagent:/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_102/jre/lib/management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:/opt/sonarqube-5.6.4/lib/jdbc/mysql/mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar
>   org.sonar.server.app.WebServer
>   /opt/sonarqube-5.6.4/temp/sq-process7860854799235034542properties
>   2016.12.30 17:10:43 INFO  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting web
>   2016.12.30 17:10:43 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatContexts] Webapp directory: /opt/sonarqube-5.6.4/web
>   2016.12.30 17:10:43 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-9000"]
>   2016.12.30 17:10:43 INFO  web[o.a.t.u.n.NioSelectorPool] Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
>   2016.12.30 17:10:44 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerImpl] SonarQube Server / 5.6.4 / 52298794f1a34a4fd713ff8d441a0c13432e40a9
>   2016.12.30 17:10:44 INFO  web[o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for
>   jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance
>   2016.12.30 17:10:45 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.DefaultServerFileSystem] SonarQube home: /opt/sonarqube-5.6.4
>   2016.12.30 17:10:46 INFO  web[o.e.plugins] [sonar-1483098032772] loaded [], sites []
>   2016.12.30 17:10:46 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin C# / 5.0 / 17ddb09047940791828dcb70c9e225f006ab11aa
>   2016.12.30 17:10:46 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Git / 1.2 / a713dd64daf8719ba4e7f551f9a1966c62690c17
>   2016.12.30 17:10:46 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Java / 3.13.1 / cf0f0c950ba3e83a87c7fe11c6ff7e63f4864bd9
>   2016.12.30 17:10:46 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin JavaScript / 2.11 / a9b1afa9ceef7079811779d9efc5f8026acb1400
>   2016.12.30 17:10:46 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SVN / 1.3 / aff503d48bc77b07c2b62abf93249d0a20bd355c
>   2016.12.30 17:10:47 INFO  web[o.s.d.c.MysqlCharsetHandler] Verify that database collation is case-sensitive
>   2016.12.30 17:10:47 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.RailsAppsDeployer] Deploying Ruby on Rails applications
>   2016.12.30 17:10:48 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.UpdateCenterClient] Update center: https://update.sonarsource.org/update-center.properties (no
>   proxy)
>   2016.12.30 17:10:48 INFO  web[o.s.s.n.NotificationService] Notification service started (delay 60 sec.)
>   2016.12.30 17:10:48 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterMetrics] Register metrics
>   2016.12.30 17:10:48 INFO  web[o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Register rules
>   2016.12.30 17:10:50 INFO  web[o.s.s.q.RegisterQualityProfiles] Register quality profiles
>   2016.12.30 17:10:52 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterNewMeasureFilters] Register measure filters
>   2016.12.30 17:10:52 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterDashboards] Register dashboards
>   2016.12.30 17:10:52 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterPermissionTemplates] Register permission templates
>   2016.12.30 17:10:52 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RenameDeprecatedPropertyKeys] Rename deprecated property keys
>   2016.12.30 17:10:52 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Index activities
>   2016.12.30 17:10:52 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Index issues
>   2016.12.30 17:10:52 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Index tests
>   2016.12.30 17:10:52 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Index users
>   2016.12.30 17:10:52 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Index views
>   2016.12.30 17:10:52 INFO  web[jruby.rack] jruby 1.7.9 (ruby-1.8.7p370) 2013-12-06 87b108a on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_102-b14
>   [linux-amd64]
>   2016.12.30 17:10:52 INFO  web[jruby.rack] using a shared (threadsafe!) runtime
>   2016.12.30 17:11:02 INFO  web[jruby.rack] keeping custom (config.logger) Rails logger instance
>   2016.12.30 17:11:02 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter
>   org.sonar.server.authentication.InitFilter@4be6bfd2
>   [pattern=/sessions/init/*]
>   2016.12.30 17:11:02 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter
>   org.sonar.server.authentication.OAuth2CallbackFilter@7b458d9d
>   [pattern=/oauth2/callback/*]
>   2016.12.30 17:11:02 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-9000"]
>   2016.12.30 17:11:02 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is started
>   2016.12.30 17:11:02 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 9000
>   2016.12.30 17:11:02 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[web] is up
>   2016.12.30 17:11:02 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[ce]: /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_102/jre/bin/java
>   -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonarqube-5.6.4/temp -javaagent:/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_102/jre/lib/management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:./lib/ce/*:/opt/sonarqube-5.6.4/lib/jdbc/mysql/mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar
>   org.sonar.ce.app.CeServer
>   /opt/sonarqube-5.6.4/temp/sq-process2065685327087970886properties
>   2016.12.30 17:11:03 INFO  ce[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting ce
>   2016.12.30 17:11:03 INFO  ce[o.s.ce.app.CeServer] Compute Engine starting up...
>   2016.12.30 17:11:03 INFO  ce[o.s.s.p.ServerImpl] SonarQube Server / 5.6.4 / 52298794f1a34a4fd713ff8d441a0c13432e40a9
>   2016.12.30 17:11:03 INFO  ce[o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for
>   jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance
>   2016.12.30 17:11:05 INFO  ce[o.s.s.p.DefaultServerFileSystem] SonarQube home: /opt/sonarqube-5.6.4
>   2016.12.30 17:11:05 INFO  ce[o.e.plugins] [sonar-1483098032772] loaded [], sites []
>   2016.12.30 17:11:05 INFO  ce[o.s.c.c.CePluginRepository] Load plugins
>   2016.12.30 17:11:07 INFO  ce[o.s.s.c.q.PurgeCeActivities] Delete the Compute Engine tasks created before Sun Jul 03 17:11:07 IST 2016
>   2016.12.30 17:11:07 INFO  ce[o.s.ce.app.CeServer] Compute Engine is up
>   2016.12.30 17:11:07 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[ce] is up

Comment: What do you mean by "my sonar home page is not loaded" ? Do you see a white page ? Did the page never finished loading ?

Comment: Did you enter the right port in your browser? Is the port accessible from outside?

Comment: Issue is resolved , I was forgetting to put context, sorry for late reply. http://localhost:9000/sonar